# Do I need to pause a video inside ngOnDestroy in a modal component?

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-video

I have a modal component with a video in it:

```
<div>
  <video controls #videoElement>
    <source src="assets/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
<div>
```

```
@ViewChild('videoElement') videoElement: ElementRef<HTMLVideoElement>;

ngOnDestroy(): void {
 this.videoElement.nativeElement.pause();
}
```

Do I need to pause the video inside "ngOnDestroy"? please explain why.

Thank you!

Comment: Depends on how your modal component works

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it's a simple modal with only text, video and close button.

Comment: Do you face a problem here?

Comment: No. I'm just asking because I saw this code and I wanted to know whether I'm missing something. A basic modal with a video in it. Do I need to pause the video inside "ngOnDestroy"? Can it cause a memory leak without it?

Comment: @mayadahan that video element will be removed from DOM as soon as your component  is destroyed so you really don't need to pause it or perform any kind of clean up to avoid mem leaks